# Restart remote target machine with gdb

Tags: macos, gdb, reboot

I'm debugging a Mac OS X kernel via a remote target (target remote-kdp) when it gets into a kernel panic. I can introspect the state of the machine at the time, but if I need to restart the machine I have to do a hard power down, which involves direct physical access. This means I can't script introspecting kernel panics.

Is it possible to ask a kernel, once it's in a panic, to do a hard reset? It's a Mac Mini on i386 if that's any help; obviously, since it's in a panic, I can't log in or do 'shutdown' or similar; but I wonder if there's some kind of assembly call or reboot command that I can use to ask the machine to restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that there's a GDB command `kdp-reboot` which will bounce a machine that's in a panic state, and bring it back up again.